# Pandas use to_datetime method on column

Tags: python, pandas

not sure if the semantics of my question are correct. So please excuse any errors. If anyone could point me in the right direction, that would help too.

I'd like to use the to_datetime method on a column of values. This is my dataframe info() output.

```
RangeIndex: 81 entries, 0 to 80
Data columns (total 9 columns):
DESCRIPTION: ACKNOWLEDGE AND ACCEPT WORK ORDER      81 non-null object
Name                                                81 non-null object
Name.1                                              81 non-null object
12/31/2018 8:16 PM                                  81 non-null object
Acknowledge NEW Work Order Ownership (deleted)      81 non-null object
AN2210W0013                                         81 non-null object
12/31/2018 7:58 AM                                  81 non-null object
Acknowledge and Accept Work Order                   81 non-null object
DESCRIPTION: ACKNOWLEDGE AND ACCEPT WORK ORDER.1    81 non-null object
```

I'd like to convert columns 4 and 7 to datatime type so I can use appropriate methods on it.

```
for x in range(len(df2)):
   pd.to_datetime(df2.iloc[x,3])
```

This is the best I got so far.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it while reading csv :

```
df = pd.read_csv('name.csv',parse_dates=[3,6],infer_datetime_format=True) # 3,6 is the column index which contain datetime
```

or after it by :

```
df['date_col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_col'])
```

Comment: Thanks, for future reference is there anyway for me to change it after it initialized by index number?